# Android Studio importing my own .jar file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I've created a java library for my android apllication with Intellij. It works fine. I've built also with Intellij.

I've coppied the .jar file to myAndroidApp/libs/ . I've imported the library using file>>project structure >> dependencies. It's ok! There is no problem. Also i can use my clases  in Android studio.

But...

When i run my application it throws this error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not expand ZIP './app/libs/GetWebDatas.jar'.
```

And the console output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not expand ZIP 
'./app/libs/GetWebDatas.jar'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info 
or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Actually i can use my GetWebDatas.jar file in another java project perfectly with no errors. But i can't use in android project.

Also i can import Jsoup or another popular .jar project to my android application. But i can't my own project.

Comment: Have you tried to create the jar file without compression?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try 
`File -> New -> New Module -> Import .JAR/.AAR Package`.